# virtual env and python client server in linux

Tags: python, linux, django, virtualenv

I have a simple django python server process which needs to be executed in linux environment (in a virtualenv python environment)

Currently one of my colleague manually logs into ssh console and starts the virtual environment via `source bin/activate` command. Thereafter python server is started using below command

```
/etc/init.d/start-python-server.sh
```

Note: This sh file starts the python server as a background process listening in port 8080

Can some one give some thoughts on improving this?

Please share in your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

you may include `source <your_env_path>/bin/activate` at the beginning of `/etc/init.d/start-python-server.sh` to automate this process

Comment: i added a line source <your_env_path>/bin/activate in the /etc/init.d/start-python-server.sh. How will i know that this server instance is mapped to an virtualenv. Any python command to view the virtual env activity status ?

Comment: `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']` will return you the active virtualenv folder as a string, if your code is running inside a virtualenv, otherwise will return an empty string. You can use this approach to know if you are inside the virtualenv. I'm unsure on what you expect as "virtualenv activity status"

Comment: apologies its a typo error  , actually i want to know the active virtual env folder. Your command returns error - does that mean virtual environment is not active ?

Comment: error as shown below : >>> import os
>>> os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'VIRTUAL_ENV'
>>>

Comment: Yes, it means you are not running python in a virtualenv. I was wrong saying it returns an empty string, to have the expected behavior you have to query the dictionary in this way: `os.environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV', '')`. If you need help including the `activate` script inside your script I kindly ask you to post the `start-python-server.sh` source code. Thanks.

Comment: Below is the script:  export "PYTHONPATH=/srv/django/code"
source /srv/virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate
nohup python -u /srv/django/code/manage.py runserver 192.168.11.11:80 > /srv/django/code/server.log &

Comment: are you using a shell other than `bash` when launching the script? Have you a shebang line at the beginning? If not, it may be a good idea to replace `source` with `.`. Another idea is to check if your `activate` script includes a definition of "`VIRTUAL_ENV`" variable.